# How to create a photo gallery in WordPress by coding?

Tags: wordpress

I created a photo gallery in WordPress, but the above gallery has a problem due to the interference of plugins. For some reason I can not remove plugins, Otherwise I would have done it.
So I said may be it could programmatically create an image gallery and add it to WordPress.But I do not know **how to do it**. I also do not know **what code to use** - html, css, js, php, etc. I only know a little bit about html.
Thanks for consulting me on this

Hoping to eradicate Covid-19

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to find a gallery plugin that is compatible with your version of wordpress and has the features you're looking for or use the built in gallery from wordpress if you're using a theme that supports it. Scope it out here https://wordpress.org/support/article/the-wordpress-gallery/.

Hand coding is definitely one route to take but with having a small amount of html knowledge the plugin route may be your best bet until you can grow those other skills.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your suggestion.
One of the reasons I said I can not use the plugin or remove the plugin that causes interference is that the site in question has so many plugins that installing or removing the plugin will cause problems.
For this reason, the issue of creating a image gallery through coding was raised.
Thank you for helping me create a image gallery for WordPress by coding

Comment: I see, that's a hairy situation. Assuming you have FTP access to add some files. You might find a gallery tutorial to follow or you can find a prebuilt one that you can modify to your needs at codepen https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=gallery. Then you wouldn't have to build it from scratch but can modify the code in real time to see what works and what doesn't.  Galleries are a dime a dozen but they can be hugely customized and unique. Good luck!